# Under-Aged Drinking for the 4 Cups on Pesach

Tags: passover, grapes-wine, dina-dmalchusa-dina, four-cups-wine

Whats the halacha to drinking wine/alcohol for a minor when they need to drink four cups of wine on pesach and if so then is in it going against Dina D'malchusa Dina?

Comment: The Rambam omits children

Comment: What about under the age of drinking (which is either 21 or 18) and over the age of a child i.e 13-21 (or 18)

Comment: Use grape juice.

Comment: religious freedom is the answer to Dina D'malchusa Dina. Even so maybe it's still simly better not to give kids that much wine anyways and grape juice may be used.

Comment: @Dude Are you sure about the grape juice? This answer ( http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/70786/1516 ) says that the lowest percentage of wine that may be used for the four cups is 4%.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will offer a partial answer to the question. Many states have exceptions to the underage drinking law that for religious purposes it is allowed. Many states also have an exception when on private, non alcohol-selling premises, with parental consent.  I got this information here: http://drinkingage.procon.org/view.resource.php?resourceID=002591.
Although this doesn't answer the halachah aspect of the question but practically the problem wont apply in many states.